# Getting content of a div includes the div itself in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html template. I want to get the first `person_line` div's content includes the person_line div.

```
<div class=​"person_row">​
    <div class=​"row-fluid person_line">​
        <div class=​"span4">​…​</div>​
        <div class=​"span8">​…​</div>​
        <div class=​"clearfix">​</div>​
    </div>​
    <div class=​"row-fluid person_line">​
        <div class=​"span4">​…​</div>​
        <div class=​"span8">​…​</div>​
        <div class=​"clearfix">​</div>​
    </div>​
</div>​
```

I tried `$($('.person_line')[0]).html()` but that does not include the `<div class=​"row-fluid person_line">`. Any ideas ? How can i get the content of person_line as html which includes the upper div.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using outerHTML -

```
$('.person_line')[0].outerHTML
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".person_line").eq(0).html();
```

more over if you want to get the children of the person_row

```
childArray = $(".person_row").find(".person_line");
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: this does not give the upper div. It gives the inside.Same with what I  done